# Zipping selected files in Android

Tags: android, zip

The application that Im developing requires the selection of files from local storage and then zipping those files. I'm selecting the files with the following code:

```
Intent chooseFile;
Intent intent;
chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.setType("file/*");
intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
```

I have no idea, however, how to zip the files once I've selected them.

Comment: That is only the code so the user can select files. Where is your code where you extract the file names or paths of the files the user selected?

Comment: Fixes for diction and grammar. The real fix for this question, however, would be to include a code sample demonstrating what you've tried to resolve your own problem.